# Python: Apple Email Content

Tags: python, email, apple-mail

I am developing a program in python that can read emails, my program can now read emails from GMAIL even with attachment but my program can't read the email that was sent from **Apple Mail**.

Unlike the email that I sent from GMAIL when I use `Message.get_payload()` in apple mail it does not have a value. I'm a newbie on python and this is my first project so please bear with me. Thank you in advance.

***Note:*** The email I sent from Apple has attachment on it.

***Update:*** I can now read the text inside the email my only problem now is how to get the attachment since when I loop all the payloads since it is multipart it only prints the text inside and this

`"[<email.message.Message object at 0x000001ED832BF6D8>, <email.message.Message object at 0x000001ED832BFDD8>]"`

Answer (score 0):

This is okay now It seems like the content type of the email i sent from Apple Mail was multipart which includes a "text/plain" which contains the text inside my email and "multipart/related" that contains the image i attached. So i just needed to check if the email is a multipart if so then loop it to print all payloads.